# Splitting string sequence into integers

Tags: c

How do you split a string:

```
char *mystring = "12345"
```

into an integer array which looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have tried something like the code below, but I'm not entirely sure if it's reliable, and I think it will be easy to break. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void) {
    char *mystring = "12345";
    int string_size, i, length;

    string_size = strlen(mystring);

    int values[string_size];

    for (i = 0; mystring[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        values[i] = mystring[i] - 48;
    }

    length = sizeof(values)/sizeof(*values);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there a more C like way I can do this?

Comment: If your code is "working", a proper place to ask *improvement* or *opinion* questions concerning it is [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: "Is there a more C like way I can do this?" - Yes: don't use _magic numbers_! Why the `48`, not `'0'`? Both are integers.

Comment: `int main(void) { const char *mystring = "12345"; const char *ptr = mystring; while (*ptr != '\0') { putchar(*ptr++); if (*ptr != '\0') putchar(' '); } putchar('\n'); return 0; }`? Or even `int main(void) { puts("1 2 3 4 5"); return 0; }`

Comment: I don't understand what is so unclear of what I'm asking. I understand that my code works, but I'm sure it's fine to see if there is an easier way to do this. Like a special c function that can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odd thing I see, which isn't itself a problem, is that you calculate the length of the string/array three different ways:

```
string_size = strlen(mystring);

for (i = 0; mystring[i] != '\0'; i++) {

length = sizeof(values)/sizeof(*values);
```

where just one method is sufficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *mystring = "12345";

    size_t length = strlen(mystring);

    int values[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        values[i] = mystring[i] - '0';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I'm still getting used to C but this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `48` with `'0'` for readability.

You can change all loops to loop until `string_size` like the first one, no need to change the method for each loop.

And finally if you're going to return that array anywhere outside of local function, you should probably `malloc()` it rather than use a local/stack variable.

But otherwise, it's pretty simple and it works.

Comment: Exchanging `'0'` for `48` is not only for readability.   `'0'` has the numeric value `48` only in ASCII and compatible character sets, and there ARE real-world character sets in which `'0'` has a different numeric value.    All standardised character sets have the digits `'0'` through `'9'` in sequence though, so subtracting `'0'` is a reliable way to convert printed digits to numeric values.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I should have used `malloc`, but I didn't think it was necessary as I was calling it within the main and the size of the array was fixed.